# Start c-program in background

Tags: shell, background-process

I want to start a C program in the background from the terminal. The program acts as bluetooth-driver, which means it has to stay open while the system is running. I tried with nohup and start-stop-daemon, but in both cases the c program gets the exit command and closes.

How can I start a C program from a terminal that then runs in the background? I want to start it and then be able to close the terminal on the gui (while the started c-programm keeps happily running).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like the program needs a controlling terminal to run (you can find out with `strace` if you don't have the source code).

You can provide the program with a controlling terminal (even when starting it as part of the system boot) by running it through `screen` (ot `tmux`).

```
screen cmd arg1 arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to fully daemonize a program, you would do

```
nohup the_command args ... </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
disown
```

Depending on your system, you should consider starting it at system startup using upstart or init or something like that.